# How to get data from sqlite table by date recent in iphone application

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an iPhone application in which I have data in the `Content` table and there is column in table `ContentAddedDateTime` where is the date time `ContentAdded` I want to select in query the most recently added contents in `ContentTable` any idea how to get this.

This is the table structure:

```
NSInteger contentID;
NSString*categoryID;
NSString*topicID;
NSString*contentType;
NSString*contentTitle;
NSString*contentAddedByUserID;
NSString*contentDescription;
NSString*contentFileName;
NSString*categoryName;
NSString*topicName;
NSString*contentSavedFileLocation;
NSString*contentSize;
NSString*contentAddedDateTime;
```

I got link that we can use start date and end date but I have only only one column `ContentAddedDateTime`.

```
select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * FROM ContentMaster Where ContentAddedDateTime='%@'",currentDateTime];
```

Comment: Downvote because for incomplete question. You have to share code whatever you tried so far. Along-with issue whatever you faced. Nobody here want to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above queries will not work in this case first of all let me clear you 1 thing that sqlite treats the 'Date' type as as String and all the comparisons are done as with Strings type so you have to convert the date to UNIX Milli seconds and then sort them manually according to the UNIX timestamp

```
time_t unixTime = (time_t) [dateObject timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: This is not correct. If the column is setup with a type of `DATETIME` then using `order by` works just fine sorting the date/time values properly. There is no need to do any kind of conversion first.

Comment: It depends on format of date you are using just change the format of date and see the effect

Answer (score 3):

Please use below structure.

```
SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name,column_name ASC|DESC;
```

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM ContentMaster
ORDER BY ContentAddedDateTime DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `order by ContentAddedDateTime desc` to the query. The first result will be the most recent.